# Convert the View Click co-ordinates from world co-ordinates to local?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing this when clicked on View I am trying to get co-ordinate of the click on the view. Now I am getting value in world co-oridates I want to get it in local View co-ordinates 
check the code below

```
public void objectClick(View objectClicked)
     {

         int [] locationOfViewInWindow=new int[2];
         int Object = objectClicked.getId();
         View img= (View)findViewById(Object);
         objectClicked.getLocationInWindow(locationOfViewInWindow);
        Log.d("Check:","locn in window" + locationOfViewInWindow[0]+ "  "+ locationOfViewInWindow[1]);
        switch (hObject) {


    case R.id.imageView1:   
            case R.id.imageView2:...... 
                    case.R.id.imageview11:
        ImageView drawable= (ImageView)findViewById(objectClicked.getId());
                Drawable d = drawable.getDrawable();

            boolean flag = d.getTransparentRegion().contains(locationOfViewInWindow[0], locationOfViewInWindow[1]);

                Log.d("Check", "Opacity" + flag);


boolean flag is returning me null because the region of transparent it is checking w.r.t to world co-ordinate 

Suggestion is appreciated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend the View class for you objects and use onTouchEvent to get the click position:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
int eventaction = event.getAction();

switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        // finger touches the screen
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // finger moves on the screen
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
        // finger leaves the screen
        break;
}

// tell the system that we handled the event and no further processing is required
return true;
```

}

You can use event.getX() and event.getY() to get the position of the touch event.